# Why do I get a Git fatal: index file smaller than expected error regularly?

Tags: git, centos, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am experiencing a very frustrating issue with using Git on my virtual machine. In my `/var/www/` directory I have a few projects with different Git repos, on occasion, and at the moment quite regularly, I re-enter the project directory and do a `git status` (or any other git command) and get errors such as the one below.

I've read how to fix this temporarily, but I can't find anything about *why* this is happening and how to stop it happening. I'm running a Vagrant VM with the versions of CentOS and Git shown below.

Could this be an issue with the way my VM is shutting down?

```
[vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco]# git status
fatal: index file smaller than expected

[vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

[vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco]# git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

I'm also finding that if I do a `git fetch origin` I get the following for each updated branch on the origin:

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/master: No such file or directory
 ! [new branch]      master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the entire story to why this is "fixed", however by disabling bash customisation (`~/.bashrc`) around Git in the `PS1` variable and shutting the virtual machine down gracefully with a `sudo shutdown -h now` rather than just closing the VM window it appears to have resolved the issue for a week or more now.